# Settings SpecializedCollections где хранится?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

Угораздило поправить файл Settings руками, параметр имеет тип SpecializedCollections, поменял как в .settings так и в .Designer.
После этого в свойствах Count образовалось число 1, подсмотренное в дебагере, на самом деле там 46 записей.

1. Удалил папку obj.
2. Через студию удалил данный параметр, создал заново с тем же именем и вставил 46 записей. В дебаге по прежнему Count равен 1.. На всякий случай повторил начиная с пункта 1, без изменений..
3. Удалил параметр, создал параметр с **другим именем**, вставил записи, все заработало..

Вопрос, где студия (2017) хранит данные о сеттингах ещё кроме этих двух файлов?

Comment: Пользовательские настройки хранятся в папке  `%userprofile%\AppData\Local\{appname}`.

Comment: Хмм, оно же из студии запускается на момент разработки, или я чего то не понимаю? То есть, все, включая конфигурации живёт в `bin/Debug` или `bin/Release`. Хотя я нашел где он третью копию прячет :) `app.config` в корне проекта, гад такой.. :)

Comment: Когда вы развернете приложение у клиента, то его _пользовательские_ настройки будут храниться именно там: `%userprofile%\AppData\Local\{appname}` - папка создастся, когда настройки будут изменены. Настройки _приложения_ будут хранится в папке рядом с экзешником. Эти настройки менять нельзя, т. к. юзеру запрещено писать в ProgramFiles, etc.

Comment: Это да, так и есть, спасибо за развернутый комментарий